# Automatically add JaversSpringDataAuditable to all instances of JPARepository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, javers

```java
@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
```

This works fine but I have a lot of repositories I need to annotate. Is there a way to configure Spring Boot so that all instances of `@Repository` will automatically use `@JaversSpringDataAuditable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about
@JaversSpringDataAuditable, but you can solve your problem by taking advantage of **how Spring Boot works** and **annotations**.

- Solution: Create and use a custom annotation that has @Repository and @JaversSpringDataAuditable.

Here is my example code:

- First, if you look inside the @Repository annotation, it is as follows.

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Repository {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Component.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

- Create a custom annotation that is the same as the annotation but has a different name.
- Now add the @JaversSpringDataAuditable we want.

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
@JaversSpringDataAuditable //<- Add
public @interface CustomRepository {
    @AliasFor(
            annotation = Component.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

- Finally, use it as follows

```java
@CustomRepository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

You can also make the annotation name more beautiful (suitable for its functionality).

I hope it will be of help. thank you

Comment: Thanks! Certainly that's a lot neater and a nice way of incorporating the additional functionality. I was hoping there would be a way for all @Repository annotations to inherit the additional annotation but if this solution is not possible I will accept this answer